How can I specify my own Terraform provider as a source to generate documentation
I am currently attempting to generate the documentation for my Terraform provider, but it always tries to get "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/pterodactyl v0.0.1". My provider is already on the registry, but I don't know how to specify the origin. I set the name as a command arg, but it still has the wrong version and "creator". I attempted to change the url in the main.go, in my go.mod, I searched through GitHub repos using tfplugindocs as well as forks of the hashicorp repo for their example hashicups provider.
The error:
Error executing command: unable to generate website: error exporting provider schema from Terraform: unable to run terraform init on provider: exit status 1

Error: Incompatible provider version

Provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/pterodactyl v0.0.1 does not have a
package available for your current platform, windows_386.

Provider releases are separate from Terraform CLI releases, so not all
providers are available for all platforms. Other versions of this provider
may have different platforms supported.

My main.go is
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    "log"

    "github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-framework/providerserver"

    "terraform-provider-pterodactyl/internal/provider"
)

// Run "go generate" to format example terraform files and generate the docs for the registry/website

// If you do not have terraform installed, you can remove the formatting command, but its suggested to
// ensure the documentation is formatted properly.
//go:generate terraform fmt -recursive ./examples/

// Run the docs generation tool, check its repository for more information on how it works and how docs
// can be customized.
//go:generate go run github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-docs/cmd/tfplugindocs generate -provider-name pterodactyl

var (
    // these will be set by the goreleaser configuration
    // to appropriate values for the compiled binary.
    version string = "dev"
)

func main() {
    var debug bool

    flag.BoolVar(&debug, "debug", false, "set to true to run the provider with support for debuggers like delve")
    flag.Parse()

    opts := providerserver.ServeOpts{
        Address: "registry.terraform.io/Luiggi33/pterodactyl",
        Debug:   debug,
    }

    err := providerserver.Serve(context.Background(), provider.New(version), opts)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
}

If any other files are needed, I can provide them

Well, I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the docs: Provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/pterodactyl v0.0.1 does not have a package available for your current platform, windows_386..

@MarkoE thats the output when I try and run go generate. My package should be at Luiggi33/pterodactyl, but i dont know why, it tries to get it from hashicorp/pterodactyl

The logged incorrect address with a hashicorp namespace is a Terraform logger issue that I believe is still open and is definitely benign. The actual utilized address for go executions is the ServeOpts{Address} which you have set correctly. @MarkoE comment is more likely root cause here than the address.

@MatthewSchuchard Thank you for that answer. How could I correc tthat package availability? I am using the goreleaser config offered in the Terraform examples and so it should be covered? I am a bit confused here, because my github releases show even a windows 386 release

I think what you are describing is the same problem discussed in issue #141

@MartinAtkins THANK YOU! Switching to amd64 in terraform and golang helped

As pointed out by @MartinAtkins, https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-docs/issues/141 solves this.
You just need have the same arch for golang and Terraform (in my case amd64)
